# Is there a word for selecting yourself as the target audience for an invention or product?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, word-usage, terminology, compounds

Let me explain this with an example. An inventor faces a problem, he decides to develop a solution for it. Initially, he is the main target audience for his invention.

I was wondering if there was an single word to describe this, a word that would mean "to solve your own problem" as a verb or "as a solution to his own problem".

I was thinking at a compound word with the prefix auto perhaps? http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/auto-

EDIT: Example usage: "The developer of the app said it started out as an (...) application (to solve his own problem). Now his company succeeds to target a more broad target audience."
Is there one word that can replace the text in brackets?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how you want to use this word. Can you include in your question an example sentence with a blank for where you want the word to go? That might help inspire possibilities.

Comment: I just made an edit adding an example sentence.

Comment: Hmm, in your particular example sentence, I'd just go with the word "personal". I'm not posting this is an answer because it doesn't actually answer your full question, but I think the word fits here because the "to solve his own problem" would be implied in this context. If I think of a word that fits and also answers your fuller question I'll post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have scoured through everything I could find, and I am starting to think that such a word simply does not exist.

The words with "self" in it seem to the only solution.

I could see a few ways to phrase it well in that format though.

"The developer said he invented the app to address his own needs. Now his company succeeded and targets a more broad target audience."

I know it's not an answer to your question, but emphasizing the fact that the developer addressed his own needs also serves the same purpose.

Comment: Yes. I agree with you. The way you phrase it is also a good solution and might actually be more clear than using a complicated word or compound to say the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

***"Self-help"*** comes to mind.  For medical issues, ***"self-diagnosed"*** and ***"self-medicated"*** are used.

EDIT - I removed my bone-headed comment about how "auto-" might not be a good prefix after @Jerry reminded me of autobiographies.  I stand by my other 2 suggestions though!

Comment: _autobiography_ comes to mind :)

Comment: @Jerry, Yeah, I'm sure those don't write themselves.  "Autoerotic" is another one.  Darn! :-)

Comment: I would say that the phrases "self-help", "self-diagnosed" and "self-medicated" apply more to problems of a personal nature rather than an inventor as in the question.

Comment: @Sam, just thinking outside the box here.  "Self-help" does not need to be solely for personal problems and you don't know from the OP's context whether the problem that requires an "invention" is of a personal nature or not.  Did he get "help"?  Yes.  Did he provide the "help" him"self"?  Yes.  There ya go! :-)

Comment: Point taken - I guess I was taking just the common meanings of both **self-help** and **inventor**.  Thinking outside the box is always welcome! :)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I don't think I have found what I was looking for, but I'm beginning to realize that there just might not be a word like this. By the way, I also added an example sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for ***"[self-appointed](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/self--appointed)"*** - having assumed a position or role without the endorsement of others.